# Getting exception in wcf service - The protocol 'net.pipe' is not supported

Tags: wcf, binding, net.pipe

I have deployment of WCF service on IIS 7 with support for Non-HTTP enabled

Under one project, I have exposed 8 different services with `wsHttp` endpoints which works fine.

I want to also expose `NetNamedPipe` bindings for the same services.

My sample `NetNamedPipe` bindings . . .

```
<netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="PassportIPCBasicEndpoint" 
         closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:05:00"
         maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered"
         hostNameComparisonMode="Exact"  >
      <readerQuotas
           maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
           maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
           maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
         <transport protectionLevel="None" />
      </security>
   </binding>
</netNamedPipeBinding>
```

And my Service tags

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="default" name="MyAccountService.AccountService">
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost/MyAccountService/v1.0/AccountService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
   </host>
   <endpoint name="PassportIPCBasicEndpoint" 
       address="net.pipe://localhost/MyAccountService/v1.0/AccountService.svc" 
       binding="netNamedPipeBinding" 
       bindingConfiguration="PassportIPCBasicEndpoint" 
       contract="MyAccountService.IAccountService"/>
</service>
```

This gives me following exception :

> The protocol 'net.pipe' is not supported.
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The protocol 'net.pipe' is not supported.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedTransportConfigurationManager.InternalGetConfiguration(String
>   scheme)
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The ChannelDispatcher at
>   'net.pipe://localhost/MyAccountService/v1.0/AccountService.svc' with
>   contract(s) '"IAccountService"' is unable to open its
>   IChannelListener.]

I have added entry for http,net.pipe in advanced site settings in IIS.

Non-HTTP support for WCF service is also installed and enabled through control panel settings.

out of 8 .svc services only one such service is able to get hold of port and I can browse it's .SVC endpoint

all other services when configured for netnamedPipe binding give me above errors.

Can some body guide me, what needs to be done to make them all get hold on port and be accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was with enabling the protocols at the correct place.
Previously i had enabled net.pipe protocol at site level.

After enabling net.pipe protocol at each virtual path of the hosted services.
It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `netNamedPipe` binding is **only** for on-the-same-machine communication - you cannot call such an endpoint from a remote machine.

Is that what you're trying to do??

`netNamedPipe` binding is great for intra-application communication on the same machine - but not for anything else, really.

Comment: yup, I am aware of this. And it is giving me this exception on the same machine.