# WCF multiple binding - Error: There was no endpoint listening

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to setup a server and client in an asp WCF project to use various WCF binding modes.

I'm getting this error when running in visual studio 2012:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:9000/BasicHttp that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.  
Unable to connect to the remote server

Server stack trace:     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    at WCF_ASMX.IWCF_Service.add(Int32[] list)    at WCF_ASMX._Default.NetPipeClient() in c:\xxx\Programming\c#\win_dotnet_sample_apps\WCF_ASMX_64bit_NamedPipe_F45\Default.aspx.cs:line 81    at WCF_ASMX._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\xxx\Programming\c#\win_dotnet_sample_apps\WCF_ASMX_64bit_NamedPipe_F45\Default.aspx.cs:line 32    at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Here is relevant part of my `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webHttpBinding_behaviour">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="basicHttpBinding_behaviour">
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="netNamedPipeBinding_behaviour">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
        <service name="WCF_Sample.WCF_Service">
            <endpoint 
                address="http://localhost:9000/BasicHttp" 
                behaviorConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_behaviour"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                contract="WCF_Sample.WCF_Service" />
            <endpoint 
                address="net.pipe://localhost/NetNamedPipe" 
                behaviorConfiguration="netNamedPipeBinding_behaviour"
                binding="netNamedPipeBinding" 
                contract="WCF_Sample.WCF_Service" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and here is my service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCF_Service
{
    [OperationContract]
    int add(int[] list);
}

[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class WCF_Service : IWCF_Service
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
    public int add(int[] list)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach(int val in list)
        {
            sum += val;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

and here is my client:

```
private void Client()
{
    ChannelFactory<IWCF_Service> httpFactory =
          new ChannelFactory<IWCF_Service>(
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9000/BasicHttp"));

    ChannelFactory<IWCF_Service> pipeFactory =
          new ChannelFactory<IWCF_Service>(
            new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/NetNamedPipe"));

    IWCF_Service httpProxy = httpFactory.CreateChannel();
    IWCF_Service pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

    string str;
    str = "http: " + httpProxy.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
    Console.WriteLine(str);

    str = "pipe: " + pipeProxy.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

---

*updating the code below:*
while I'm still getting a similar error:

```
The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://wcf_sample/' could not be found on your local machine.
[PipeException: The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://wcf_sample/' could not be found on your local machine. ]

[EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://wcf_sample/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.]
```

*new web.config:*

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="netNamedPipeBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="netNamedPipeBehavior" name="WCF_Sample.WCF_Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="netNamedPipeEndPt" contract="WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://WCF_Sample" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

*new client code:*

```
private void Client()
{
    ChannelFactory<IWCF_Service> pipeFactory =
      new ChannelFactory<IWCF_Service>(
        new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
        new EndpointAddress(
          "net.pipe://WCF_Sample"));

    IWCF_Service pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
    string str;
    str = "pipe: " + pipeProxy.add(new int[] { 1, 2 });
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

*When I open the service in the browser, I get this error:*

```
The service class of type WCF_Sample.WCF_Service both defines a ServiceContract and inherits a ServiceContract from type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service. Contract inheritance can only be used among interface types.  If a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute, it must be the only type in the hierarchy with ServiceContractAttribute.  Consider moving the ServiceContractAttribute on type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service to a separate interface that type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service implements.
[InvalidOperationException: The service class of type WCF_Sample.WCF_Service both defines a ServiceContract and inherits a ServiceContract from type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service. Contract inheritance can only be used among interface types.  If a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute, it must be the only type in the hierarchy with ServiceContractAttribute.  Consider moving the ServiceContractAttribute on type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service to a separate interface that type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service implements.]
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceReflector.GetInterfaces(Type service) +12922331
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts) +248
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +146
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +46
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +146
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +30
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +494
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1434
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/WCF_Service.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The service class of type WCF_Sample.WCF_Service both defines a ServiceContract and inherits a ServiceContract from type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service. Contract inheritance can only be used among interface types.  If a class is marked with ServiceContractAttribute, it must be the only type in the hierarchy with ServiceContractAttribute.  Consider moving the ServiceContractAttribute on type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service to a separate interface that type WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service implements..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +489276
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +350382
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9691825
```

Comment: How are you **hosting** your service? Are you using IIS? Or a self-hosting approach?

Comment: Currently I'm hosting both the server and the client in visual studio. The server is my wcf service and the client is my asp app; so I guess that's what you call self-hosting.

Comment: Two questions: (1) Are the client and server on the same machine? If not, then Named Pipes will not work. (2) Can you provide the server stack trace? (if Q1 was yes).

Comment: yes and yes. I noticed a strange error when I open the service in the browser. I think that's the key...so I'm going to post that.

Comment: Am I correct to say that because I used [ServiceContract] in WCF_Service, I should not have specified an interface IWCF_Service because wcf already makes an invisible Interface for me?

Comment: See my update and in regards to this new information.

Comment: Are you still receiving the same error?

Comment: Yes Derek. I tried a good approach that is to right click on references and discover the services to add. However, that also errors out with the same error as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214390/getting-exception-in-wcf-service-the-protocol-net-pipe-is-not-supported?rq=1  I do not quite understand the answer posted there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not specifying the service contract correctly.

Change `contract="WCF_Sample.WCF_Service"` to `contract="WCF_Sample.IWCF_Service" />`.

**Update Per Comment:**

It is considered best practice to have an interface and to implement it. I would remove the Attributes from the Service Library and place them on the Service Contract. This should solve your problem.

However, if you wish to skip the interface then you would need to remove `IWCF_Service` from your project completely and to change your web.config to this:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="netNamedPipeBehavior" name="WCF_Sample.WCF_Service">
  <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="netNamedPipeEndPt" contract="WCF_Sample.WCF_Service" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that...after fixing that, I still get that error. I also tried creating the config file from scratch and shall update the code above.